# How to get column name that matched the query in Solr..?

Tags: solr

I am using Apache Solr version 6.6.1 for searching..!!

Scenario
Suppose I have 3 fields in a document **product_name, product_category, product_desc** On which search is to be performed.

So, If a user type **LED** then autosuggest must show options like this :
**LED in product name

LED in product category

LED in product**

*Also, if "LED" is not found in any field it should not show in the autosuggest option.*

Let me know if it is possible using Solr query or there is any other way to do it.

Comment: it's not clear what kind of columns you're talking about?

Comment: Here columns are similar to the fields name in solr.

Comment: Have you looked at the output from `debugQuery`? You should be able to parse that to see which fields and values resulted in hits (and the score it contributed).